# C++ How to call a Child Method from Parent

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-errors, pure-virtual

I'm working on a small project, and I found myself in a situation like this :

```
class A{}

class B : class A {
    public:
        void f();
        int getType() const;
    private:
        int type;
}

class C : class A{
    public:
        int getType() const;
    private:
        int type;
}
```

I want to know if there's a way to call the `f()` function `(in class B`) from an object of `type A`?

I tried this but it says function `f()` cannot be found in `class A` :

```
int main(){
    vector<A*> v;
    // v initialized with values of A ...
    if (v->getType() == 1){             // 1 is the type of B
        v->f();
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems you are approaching the problem with a wrong approach, inheritance in OOP does not work this way. Better explain your original problem which led to this route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've seen, this code won't compile because `A` doesn't have an `f` method. In order to make it work, you'd have to explicitly downcast the pointer:

```cpp
B* tmp = dynamic_cast<B*>(v);
tmp->f();
```

Comment: i dont think this will solve the original problem since the dynamic cast is not supposed to be known (eg it can very well be C class instead of B)

Comment: @NikosM. but `C` has no `f` so the cast fails and all is fine... (maybe `if (tmp) tmp->f();` would be better)

Comment: ok, but still I think this is not the way to go, but I am not the OP

Comment: OP has implemented their own type checking mechanism - this is preceded by `if (v->getType() == 1)`

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, with your current classes, you can't call `getType()` on an A*. Because the interface of A doesn't have this method. To solve this problem, you either need to make `getType` a virtual function in A, or move the `type` field to base class A (as `protected`) and initialize it in the constructors of the child classes. Let me show you the first method, because I think it is a better approach, since it makes the objective of this function more clear.

```
class A {
public:
  virtual int getType() { return 0; } // or delete the function: ... getType() = 0;
}

class B : public A {
public:
  int getType() override { return 1; }
}
```

With these classes, once you create an instance of B, getType() returns 1 when called on that instance, whether it is pointed to by an `A*` or `B*`:

```
A *object = new B();
object->getType(); // returns 1
```

Now, if you need to access the `f()` from B, you can again add it as a virtual method to A's interface, or make a cast to `B*`.

Using a virtual method:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void f() { /* a default action maybe? */ }
}

class B : public A {
public:
  void f() /* override if you want */ { /* whatever this function does in B */ }
}

...

for (A *ptr : v)
  ptr->f();
```

Using a cast:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual int getType() { return 0; }
}

class B : public A {
public:
  void f();

  int getType() override { return 1; }
}

...

for (A *ptr : v)
  if (ptr->getType() == 1)
    dynamic_cast<B*>(ptr)->f();
```